# Center image vertically and horizontally inside of DIV with float:left?

Tags: css, html, center

I need a working solution to do a trival task of centering images with different dimensions, to a square div when float:left is used to place images in rows.I use div inside of div to do the trick :

```
 .outer-element{ //wrap tile div
     display:table-cell;
     width:300px;height:300px;
     text-align:center ;
     vertical-align:middle ;
     float:left;
     margin-bottom:15px;
 }
 .inner-element{ //div with image inside
     display:inline-block;
 }
```

BUT I must use use float: left for outer-element to put images into rows and when I do images are not centered vertically (they are aligned to top border of the div) I tried some other CSS codes but *float:left* always makes images not vertically centered.

Comment: Please post a live demo, at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/), or similar to show what you're working with and demonstrate what's going wrong.

Comment: Float doesn't apply to table cells.

Comment: must put demo in http://www.jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Remove `float:left;` from your `.outer-element` as it conflicts with how the table-cell displays content. If you need to float the container left, place the `.outer-element` within another container that floats left.

**HTML**

```
<div class="fl">
    <div class="outer-element">
        <div class="inner-element">
            <img src="http://thecybershadow.net/misc/stackoverflow.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.fl {float:left;}
.outer-element{
    display:table-cell;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background:#666;
    text-align:center;
    margin-bottom:15px;
}
.inner-element{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

**Exmaple:**
http://jsfiddle.net/xQEBH/17/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

try like this http://jsfiddle.net/aEfwC/

```
<div align="center">
    <div class="outer-element">
    <div class="image"></div>
</div>   
</div>


.outer-element
{
     width:300px;height:300px;
     float:left;
     background-color:#2a2a2a;
    position:relative;
 }
.image
{
width:128px;
height:128px;
background:url(http://thecybershadow.net/misc/stackoverflow.png);
vertical-align:middle; 
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Css...

```
.outer-element{ //wrap tile div
     display:table-cell;
     width:300px;height:300px;
     text-align:center ;
     vertical-align:middle ;
     float:left;
     margin-bottom:15px;
 }
.inner-element{ //div with image inside
     display:inline-block;
 }
```

Just add the following that you want your elements to be floated left...

```
.outer-element:before{content: "."; height: 0; overflow: hidden; visibility: hidden; float: left;}
```

Hope this helps....