# Center an image veritcally and horizontally

Tags: css

I am trying to centre an image vertically and horizontally in a container. The size of the container is fixed, however the image can be of any size and needs to fit in the box. I have managed so far to get it centred horizontally but not vertically.

I have done some googling and tried some different methods but they either don't work, or do one or the other.

Here is a simplified sample of what I have so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZLXq2/

### EDIT

Just right after I posted this up, I solved it! Typical. The solution can be found here

http://jsfiddle.net/ZLXq2/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scratch that, I have managed to fix it, and for anyone hitting the issue, it can be seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZLXq2/1/

Comment: This was the correct answer for my issue, however the post by Lazar that mentions using max-width and max-height saved me using javascript to change images to fit the box. It doesn't work for images smaller than the box, which my javascript did but at least it would save images being stretched.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to support IE7, you can use the solution found here:
[Center image vertically and horizontally inside of DIV with float:left?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819931/center-image-vertically-and-horizontally-inside-of-div-with-floatleft)

It doesn't need any JS.

Comment: The reason I used javascript was to make sure the size of the image was resized to fit in the smaller box. In the link you provided, if you link it to a bigger image, the box size gets bigger

Comment: You should consider using CSS values like max-width and max-height for the image. Try to use less JS when possible.

Comment: Would doing that keep the proportions of the image though? The images could be of any size and/or dimensions. And I need to keep them in the box, along with preventing them being stretched etc

Comment: Yes, it would keep the proportions of the image.

Comment: If you end up using it, be sure to accept the answer ;) Cheers!

Comment: I didn't use your float to fix the initial problem (I used the CSS from my jsFiddle), however the max-width and max-height worked for me which saved me using javascript.